# If a dice game is solely luck, how can one piece reliably win?

Tags: probability, game-theory, dice

We've been reading Christmas books with our son this season and one was a Jolly Postman book with a board game. The game needs a counter per player and a die.

It's very simple - roll the dice and move the number. Some spaces move you forward, some backwards, some miss a turn etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xLp0.jpg

I know about the probabilities of rolling 1-6 on the die, and the squares you land on are chance - however we've played this little game over 10 times and every single time - whoever has the yellow counter wins. It doesn't matter if I use the yellow counter, or if my son uses the yellow counter - they will always win (so far).

Should the maths determine that technically we should win 50/50? Or could there be some other reasonable explanation, and of we played more then we should see the lock even out?

Comment: There is likely a slight edge in going first since if both players end up needing exactly $k$ turns to reach the end, the first player wins. I don't think the color of the counter matters unless yellow always goes first. But even then, I bet going first doesn't give that much of an edge.

Comment: We've both gone first (albeit I've gone first less) but every time someone uses the red counter they lose. A couple of times I've had a good run then get sent back to the start half way round and lose. Every time. I want to say it's cursed - but that can't be the answer!

Comment: I do not know how often you played this. Even in a $50-50$ game , long consecutive wins or losses are possible, otherwise it would be trivial to beat the casino with a martingale. Did you try to determine the probability that the first player wins (at least approximately) ?